# Why does order() in R generate NAs when passing in a subsetted dataframe?

Tags: r, columnsorting

Having a little trouble understanding what is going on here, it appears to me that both methods for ordering the data frame below are equivalent.

Our dataframe,

```
cols <- c("chr","id","value")
df <-   data.frame(c(1:5),c("ENSG1","ENSG2","ENSG3","ENSG4","ENSG5"),runif(5,5.0,10.0))
names(df) <- cols
df <- df[sample(nrow(df)),]
df

chr    id    value
5      ENSG5 8.913645
2      ENSG2 6.117744
4      ENSG4 8.558403
3      ENSG3 9.625546
1      ENSG1 6.105577
```

Now, method 1:

```
df[order(df[,c("chr","id")]),]

chr    id    value
1      ENSG1 6.105577
2      ENSG2 6.117744
3      ENSG3 9.625546
4      ENSG4 8.558403
5      ENSG5 8.913645
NA    <NA>       NA
NA    <NA>       NA
NA    <NA>       NA
NA    <NA>       NA
NA    <NA>       NA
```

Which throws in NAs for some curious reason, while passing in df columns to `order()` as in,

method 2:

```
df[order(df$chr,df$id),]

chr    id    value
1      ENSG1 6.105577
2      ENSG2 6.117744
3      ENSG3 9.625546
4      ENSG4 8.558403
5      ENSG5 8.913645
```

alternatively does not.

Can someone explain why method 1 and method 2 are not interchangeable?

Comment: I believe that this is because `order` is coercing your `df` to `matrix` and then sorting that. Since matrices in `R` are nothing but vectors with a `dim` attribute, the output is the order of the first column followed by the order of the second column. So what indexes `df` is a vector of length 10. Try to run just `order` with no `df` and see the result.

Comment: Order doesn't work on a subsetted data frame because it doesn't work on data frames at all. It does work when you call it on vectors (which just happen to be columns in your data frame).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we look at `?order`, it's first arguments are documented as:

> a sequence of numeric, complex, character or logical vectors, all of the same length, or a classed R object.

Nothing there really suggests that it would work on a data frame. A "classed R object" is a bit vague, and suggests that a data frame won't throw an error, but it certainly doesn't say "or a data frame".

The *Description* says:

> See the examples for how to use these functions to sort data frames, etc.

When you call `order` or a data frame, you can see what happens:

```
order(data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 5:1))
# [1]  1 10  2  9  3  8  4  7  5  6
```

It looks like it coerces the data frame to a vector, and orders it. Not generally very useful. This is why when you run `df[order(df[,c("chr","id")]),]` you get the `NA` rows. Your input data frame had 2 columns hence the `order()` output had twice as many rows as the data frame.

You have already found the correct way to order a data frame, which is to give actual vectors to `order`. The vectors can be individual columns of your data frame or they can be other vectors of the correct length.